# iOS 7.0.3 Blur Effect Behind Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

In iOS 7.0.0 using a translucent navigation bar in a UINavigationController added a nice blur effect to the content behind the bar but it seemed to change the color saturation of the navigation bar.

In iOS 7.0.3 it seems like the saturation issue is fixed but you don't get the blur effect anymore. The content behind the navigation bar is just shown as it is. Does anyone know if it's somehow possible to get the blur effect back or if it's possible to create the blur effect programmatically?

Comment: Are you sure it depends on iOS 7 version ? My impression was that, since first public iOS 7 version, that blur was never displayed on iPhone 4 (but was on newer devices, iPhone 4S, 5 & 5S). What device do you test on ?

Comment: I'm using the simulator and I've tested both the 4-inch and 3.5-inch simulator is the same. I'm fairly certain that this is due to the iOS version because I just updated xcode and the blur effect and the color issue changed.